# connectivityResult returns null in flutter app's startup?

Tags: flutter, dart, connectivity, flutter-plugin, flutter-packages

I am using connectivity: ^0.4.6 plugin for checking the connectivity in the flutter app. My code is as below:

```
Future<void> main() async {

  StreamSubscription connectivitySubscription;

  ConnectivityResult _previousResult;

  connectivitySubscription = Connectivity()
    .onConnectivityChanged
    .listen((ConnectivityResult connectivityResult) {
      if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.none) {
        nav.currentState.push(CupertinoPageRoute(
          builder: (BuildContext _) => NoConnectivityView()));
      } else if (_previousResult == ConnectivityResult.none) {
        nav.currentState.push(CupertinoPageRoute(
          builder: (BuildContext _) =>  LoginScreen()));
      }

      _previousResult = connectivityResult;
    });

  Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

It's working perfectly when the connection changes after the app starts. But if there is no connection in initial state its not working. `connectivityResult` is null this time.

How can I solve this?

Comment: So if you were to print the value of `connectivityResult` aka the variable from the callback, it would be null?

Comment: not working in startup, if internet connection is off..\

Comment: Why don't you just add an edge case for null?

Comment: How can I add ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're listening to the connectivity of the device, this callback will fire multiple times so at one moment it might be null but at another moment it won't be null.

I have added a null case for you:

```
Future<void> main() async {

  StreamSubscription connectivitySubscription;

  ConnectivityResult _previousResult;

  connectivitySubscription = Connectivity()
    .onConnectivityChanged
    .listen((ConnectivityResult connectivityResult) {
      if (connectivityResult == null || connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.none) {
        nav.currentState.push(CupertinoPageRoute(
          builder: (BuildContext _) => NoConnectivityView()));
      } else if (_previousResult == ConnectivityResult.none) {
        nav.currentState.push(CupertinoPageRoute(
          builder: (BuildContext _) =>  LoginScreen()));
      }

      _previousResult = connectivityResult;
    });

  Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Comment: Its not firing when the app in startup and the connection is off.. But after changing the connection its working perfectly.. What I have to do is to navigate to NoConnectivityView() in startup itself if the connection is not there..

Comment: Maybe it's because you're doing it before the app even starts...

Comment: This code should be after the app gets initialized aka after `MyApp` gets loaded.

Comment: added it in initstate of MyApp.. but in startup its not working

Comment: Remove it entirely from the `main` function, it's not supposed to be there.

Comment: Then where should be added?

Comment: Its already there in initstate of MyApp.. working perfectly everything except the startup issue

Comment: Did you remove it from `main`?

Comment: For future readers, you can directly check the initial state of the app using `await Connectivity().checkConnectivity()` and then listen to the changes.